# JSON Parser to TXT files

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, text

I use a programme called FIBA LiveStats, which records basketball game statistics and processes them in [links like this](http://www.fibalivestats.com/data/848382/data.json).

What I want to be able to do is use the data on our livestreams. OBS Studio only uses .txt files to import text that can be updated live. It doesn't work with JSON etc. I would like to take a string of a specific person, or a score, for example:

```
               "comp":{
              "sMinutesAverage":"26:31",
              "sPointsAverage":8,
              "sReboundsTotalAverage":3.75,
              "sAssistsAverage":1.25
           },
           "name":"T. Maihi"
```

and then use it on stream as a txt file. Now this data updates live from the URL I provided. So every time an action is created on the programme, it sends the data to that URL and updates what is relevant. Say this player were to score a point, her average will go up.

What I would like to is take a string of data, for example:

```
               "sMinutes":"24:21", <!-- LINE 3143 EXAMPLE -->
```

and turn the data there (24:21) and convert it to a text file that lives on my computer that OBS Studio can read.

So what this would do is create say [player_T_Maihi_sMinutes.txt] and inside would be the data provided from the .JSON file. If there is a way to do this, it would be great for some help, or I would really like to code this myself. I have absolutely no experience with .JSON files.

Thanks!

Comment: .JSON is just text with a different extension save it with .txt and everything will be Rosy colored sunglasses.

Comment: What is the format of the txt file that you need?

Comment: I am just trying to get it to plain text. So when it opens, it's a single item of data rather than anything else

Comment: You question is unclear. A JSON file is a TXT file. JSON data in memory is TXT data in memory. You can use JSON.parse to deserialize JSON text data to a JavaScript data structure. JSON.stringify goes the other way, you use it to serialize a JavaScript data structure to JSON text data.